# Setting note privacy to groups instead of just author

Tags: contacts, groups, php

[On Civicrm 5.19.1, Drupal 7]
**Is it possible within Civicrm to make a new privacy setting that limits viewing notes to an entire group, and not only the author?**

We would like all tarification people to be able to see each other's notes on a contact, but not our clients.

I've seen [here](https://civicrm.org/blog/allenshaw/adding-privacy-and-comments-civicrm-notes) and [here](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php%3Ftopic=22633.0.html) that it was not implemented yet by 2011, but has it become possible since?

I have added the screen with the heading "edit Privacy level for notes Option" (Notes tab>Add note>wrench). I anticipated being able to add group privacy here, but I don't see how to specify anything.

[image: **the edit screen for "Edit Privacy level for notes Option"**]

I've seen [this PHP hook](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_notePrivacy/#summary), is the only solution using this in additional PHP code?

Comment: Probably the hook is the way to go. Also check at https://civicrm.org/extensions - I didn't see anything but you might find something.