# private notes: how to restrict visibility to a certain group?

Tags: privacy

private notes is very  usefull , but I miss the functionality to restrict visibility to a group of users. 
Is there a way to realise this in civicrm or is it necessary to make a new extension?

Comment: I think this is the same question as https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/33757/setting-note-privacy-to-groups-instead-of-just-author. It seems like making an extension is the way to go. I'd suggest posting there and maybe you can collaborate with @eics on making the extension.

Comment: since this one got the answer first i Closed the other as duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try this extension: https://github.com/AlainBenbassat/eu.businessandcode.notepermissions

It creates a permission in your CMS for each note type you create in CiviCRM.
You can then selectively assign these permissions to users who have to see the corresponding notes.

The extension has not been extensively tested, so I'm looking forward to user feedback.

Comment: Works fine. Very usefull.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment it is necessary to make a new extension AFAIK.

Comment: I think this question is a duplicate of https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/33757/setting-note-privacy-to-groups-instead-of-just-author, but it wouldn't let me vote to close.

Comment: @Demerit I think that is because that question doesn't have an answer.